# Enumeration on the top of figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, enumerate

I am trying to itemize a figure, but if I do the following, I end up getting Circle on the bottom of the figure

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}

\item[Circle]

\begin{tikzpicture}

\scope
\clip (1,0) circle (1);

\endscope

\draw (4,0) circle (1.7) (4,1.7)  node [text=black,above]{$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

How do I make 'Circle' to be on the left side of the top of the figure?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

You can name the node, i.e. `node (a) {$A$};`, and then add `baseline=(a)` to the `tikzpicture` options.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}

\item[Circle]

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a)]

\begin{scope}
\clip (1,0) circle (1);

\end{scope}

\draw (4,0) circle (1.7) (4,1.7)  node (a) [text=black,above]{$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in a `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}

\item[Circle]
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip (1,0) circle (1);
\end{scope}
\draw (4,0) circle (1.7) (4,1.7)  node [text=black,above]{$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```